# Is my approach correct for concurrent network requests?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I wrote a web crawler and I want to know if my approach is correct. The only issue I'm facing is that it stops after some hours of crawling. No exception, it just stops.

1 - the private members and the constructor:

```
private const int CONCURRENT_CONNECTIONS = 5;

private readonly HttpClient _client;

private readonly string[] _services = new string[2] {
    "https://example.com/items?id=ID_HERE",
    "https://another_example.com/items?id=ID_HERE"
}

private readonly List<SemaphoreSlim> _semaphores;

public Crawler() {
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = CONCURRENT_CONNECTIONS;
    
    _client = new HttpClient();
    _semaphores = new List<SemaphoreSlim>();
    
    foreach (var _ in _services) {
        _semaphores.Add(new SemaphoreSlim(CONCURRENT_CONNECTIONS));
    }
}
```

- Single `HttpClient` instance.
- The `_services` is just a string array that contains the URL, they are **not** the same domain.
- I'm using semaphores (one per domain) since I read that it's not a good idea to use the network queue (I don't remember how it calls).

---

2 - The `Run` method, which is the one I will call to start crawling.

```
public async Run(List<int> ids) {
    const int BATCH_COUNT = 1000;
    
    var svcIndex = 0;
    var tasks = new List<Task<string>>(BATCH_COUNT);
    
    foreach (var itemId in ids) {
        tasks.Add(DownloadItem(svcIndex, _services[svcIndex].Replace("ID_HERE", $"{itemId}")));
        
        if (++svcIndex >= _services.Length) {
            svcIndex = 0;
        }
        
        if (tasks.Count >= BATCH_COUNT) {
            var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            
            await SaveDownloadedData(results);
            
            tasks.Clear();
        }
    }
    
    if (tasks.Count > 0) {
        var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            
        await SaveDownloadedData(results);
        
        tasks.Clear();
    }
}
```

- `DownloadItem` is an async function that actually makes the GET request, note that I'm not awaiting it here.
- If the number of tasks reaches the `BATCH_COUNT`, I will await all to complete and save the results to file.

---

3 - The `DownloadItem` function.

```
private async Task<string> DownloadItem(int serviceIndex, string link) {
    var needReleaseSemaphore = true;
    var result = string.Empty;
    
    try {
        await _semaphores[serviceIndex].WaitAsync();
        
        var r = await _client.GetStringAsync(link);
        
        _semaphores[serviceIndex].Release();
        
        needReleaseSemaphore = false;
        
        // DUE TO JSON SIZE, I NEED TO REMOVE A VALUE (IT'S USELESS FOR ME)
        var obj = JObject.Parse(r);
        
        if (obj.ContainsKey("blah")) {
            obj.Remove("blah");
        }
        
        result = obj.ToString(Formatting.None);
    } catch {
        result = string.Empty;
        
        // SINCE I GOT AN EXCEPTION, I WILL 'LOCK' THIS SERVICE FOR 1 MINUTE.
        // IF I RELEASED THIS SEMAPHORE, I WILL LOCK IT AGAIN FIRST.
        if (!needReleaseSemaphore) {
            await _semaphores[serviceIndex].WaitAsync();
            needReleaseSemaphore = true;
        }
        
        await Task.Delay(60_000);
    } finally {
        // RELEASE THE SEMAPHORE, IF NEEDED.
        if (needReleaseSemaphore) {
            _semaphores[serviceIndex].Release();
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

---

4- The function that saves the result.

```
private async Task SaveDownloadedData(List<string> myData) {
    using var fs = new FileStream("./output.dat", FileMode.Append);
    
    foreach (var res in myData) {
        var blob = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(res);
        
        await fs.WriteAsync(BitConverter.GetBytes((uint)blob.Length));
        await fs.WriteAsync(blob);
    }
    
    await fs.DisposeAsync();
}
```

---

5- Finally, the `Main` function.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args) {
    var crawler = new Crawler();
    var items = LoadItemIds();
    
    await crawler.Run(items);
}
```

---

After all this, is my approach correct? I need to make millions of requests, will take some weeks/months to gather all data I need (due to the connection limit).

After 12 - 14 hours, it just stops and I need to manually restart the app (memory usage is ok, my VPS has 1 GB and it never used more than 60%).

Comment: Read about how to take a "hang dump" and then how to debug one. You are likely leaking some non-memory resource. You may also be deadlocking on something

Comment: Cant say for sure, but you might want to read up on TCP Socket Exhaustion - its possible that you might be hitting this .

Comment: You have N services and M Ids. But as it is seen on the point 2 you are only making M requests in total, and not what you're expecting it to be, N*M requests.

Comment: In "3" you catch any Exception but you do not log it anywhere. That would be the first thing, I'd change. Also, to make your life easier, I'd recommend to have a look into "DataFlow" and "Polly".